# Torchscripting: How to script function in custom class that inherits from nn.Sequential?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, torchscript

I am currently trying to convert the FFB6D pose estimation model to TorchScript.
Since it has a lot of conditional flows, I have to torch.jit.script it. However, I am totally new to Scripting and the docs don't really tell much about error handling and how to understand some errors properly …

I instantiated the model with the best checkpoint and supplied a batch size of 1 to my model with the data generator that is also used for training the network:

```
model.to('cpu')
for (batch_idx, batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
    scripted_module = torch.jit.script(model, batch)
print(scripted_module.graph)
```

This is the class i'm trying to use inside of my Network, that has to be scripted:

```
class Seq(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, input_channels):
        super(Seq, self).__init__()
        self.count = 0
        self.current_channels = input_channels

    
    def conv2d(
        self,
        out_size,
        kernel_size=(1, 1),
        stride=(1, 1),
        padding=(0, 0),
        dilation=(1, 1),
        activation=nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        bn=False,
        init=nn.init.kaiming_normal_,
        bias=True,
        preact=False,
        name="",
        norm_layer=BatchNorm2d,
    ):
        # type: (Seq, int, Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Any, bool, Any, bool, bool, str, AnyStr) -> Seq

        self.add_module(
            str(self.count),
            Conv2d(
                self.current_channels,
                out_size,
                kernel_size=kernel_size,
                stride=stride,
                padding=padding,
                dilation=dilation,
                activation=activation,
                bn=bn,
                init=init,
                bias=bias,
                preact=preact,
                name=name,
                norm_layer=norm_layer,
            ),
        )
        self.count += 1
        self.current_channels = out_size

        return self
```

I tried to use the decorator @torch.jit.script above the function.
Now whenever I try to run it it throws following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_model.py", line 11, in <module>
    import train_custom
  File "/home/miriam/ArtNetML/ffb6d/train_custom.py", line 36, in <module>
    import models.pytorch_utils as pt_utils
  File "/home/miriam/ArtNetML/ffb6d/models/pytorch_utils.py", line 270, in <module>
    class Seq(nn.Sequential):
  File "/home/miriam/ArtNetML/ffb6d/models/pytorch_utils.py", line 330, in Seq
    norm_layer=BatchNorm2d,
  File "/home/miriam/anaconda3/envs/ffb6d/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/jit/_script.py", line 1311, in script
    qualified_name, ast, _rcb, get_default_args(obj)
RuntimeError: 
Unknown type name 'Seq':
# type: (Seq, int, Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int], Any, bool, Any, bool, bool, str, AnyStr) -> Seq
         ~~~ <--- HERE
```

It’s a really big network, so i much rather send a link to the github page with the network file:
[FFB6D.py Model](https://github.com/ethnhe/FFB6D/blob/master/ffb6d/models/ffb6d.py)

This is the file with the Conv2d Class implementation where the error occurs (in line 168, I guess?):
[Pytorch_Utils.py Conv2D](https://github.com/ethnhe/FFB6D/blob/master/ffb6d/models/pytorch_utils.py)

I am totally lost and really don't understand the error message. I also don't know the best practice of tracing parts of the model, since it's not my own network and I am not really familiar with the size of input tensors to create example input data..

When im not using the decorator i get the "Could not get qualified name for class 'conv2d': __module__ can't be None." Error.
I checked the Origin of this error in line 1015 of [jit_internal.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e56d3b023818f54553f2dc5d30b6b7aaf6b6a325/torch/_jit_internal.py#L930) but couldn't figure out the problem aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You're class `Seq` is still not defined as you are defining a function inside of this class, it is like a snake beating it's own queue ! And when you use torch.script, the comment with `Seq` will lead to an error because the definition of your class is still not done at this step of the code.

If you want to create a method that outputs an object of the class it is member of, you have this kind of semantic with `""`:

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self, number: int) -> None:
        self.n = number

    def randomObject(self) -> "myClass":
        return myClass(ramdom.randint(1,100))
```